# FormData() input[type=file]

Tags: javascript, formdata

https://codepen.io/Galtran/pen/BGYRoX?editors=1011

```html
<form id="form" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        <label for="upload">Прикрепить файл</label>
        <input id="upload" name="upload" type="file" accept="image/png" multiple>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="name1">Имя</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" pattern="[A-zА-яЁё]{3,}" required>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="tel">Телефон</label>
        <input id="tel" name="tel" type="tel" placeholder="8-123-456-78-90" required>
    </p>
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

```js
'use strict';
var form = document.querySelector('#form'),
     upload = form.querySelector('#upload'),
     username = form.querySelector('#name'),
     tel = form.querySelector('#tel');

var onFormSubmit = function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      var formData = new FormData(form);
      // var formData = new FormData();

      // var uploadValue = upload.files,
      //   nameValue = username.value,
      //   telValue = tel.value;

      // formData.append('upload', uploadValue);
      // formData.append('name', nameValue);
      // formData.append('tel', telValue);

      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

      request.addEventListener('load', function () {
        if (request.status === 200) {
          console.log(request.response);
        } else {
          console.log('Статус ответа: ' + request.status + ' ' + request.statusText);
        }
      });

      request.addEventListener('error', function () {
        console.log('Произошла ошибка соединения');
      });
      request.addEventListener('timeout', function () {
        console.log('Запрос не успел выполниться за ' + request.timeout + 'мс');
      });

      request.timeout = 10000;

      request.open("POST", "#");
      request.send(formData);
    };

    form.addEventListener('submit', onFormSubmit);
```

Несколько вопросов:

1. В конструктор FormData передаю аргументом форму. В отладчике ставлю точку останова и ожидаю увидеть в переменной formData пары ключ-значения инпутов формы, но там пустой конструктор FormData{}. Если (раскомментировать) передать в переменную formData = FormData() без аргумента и добавить значения самостоятельно, то они там появляются, как свойства объекта formData. Кроме списка загруженных файлов. В первом варианте так и должно быть? И как себя проверить, что нужные данные попали в форму?
2. Атрибут input[type=file] - accept="image/png"
   Я так понял, что это не валидация, а что-то, вроде, фильтра в диалоговом окне загрузки. Т.е. валидацию надо делать самостоятельно.
3. стр 5 и стр 15 в js. переменная username была названа просто name и в отладчике nameValue возвращало undefined. Пока не понял, с чем это  связано.
4. Есть ли какой-нибудь тестовый сервер для проверки или как себя проверить, что нужные данные правильно отправлены?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. То, что в объекте *FormData* есть значение вы можете проверить так

   console.log(formData.get('name'))

Это самый простой способ. Кроме того, при отправке данных во вкладке *Network* вы сможете увидеть все поля, которые передала форма.

2. Да, в диалоговом окне будет доступны для выбора только *.png файлы.
3. Вопрос не совсем понятен: ваш код выведет значение *nameValue* в консоль, если его раскомментировать(и добавить *console.log('nameValue', nameValue);* )
4. Так же как и в вопросе 1 - вы можете посмотреть всё, что ушло на сервер во вкладке *Network* отладчика